# Angular object used within ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table with the rows being created using ngRepeat. Is it possible to use the object from the ngRepeat within the tag that the repeat is used?

i.e.

```
<tr onclick="document.location='{{object.url}}'" ng-repeat="object in objects">
     <td>{{object.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Is it possible to use the object in the same tag like this?

Comment: I've never understand these "is it possible" questions… Why the hell don't you simply try⁉

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the idea of the ng-repeat tag.

You have to use ng-click instead though.